# How to share code between packages in monorepo but don't expose is publicly?

Tags: node.js, typescript, monorepo

Let's say that I have a monorepo with few packages.

- services
- services-nestjs

Both packages are publicly accessible. The `services` packages does not publicly expose an interface called `EmailStrategy` so it cannot be imported by someone who installs it. However, I need to import the `EmailStrategy` in the other one `services-nestjs` package. Is there some kind of "package" access modifier?

I tried to export the interface and mark it as "internal" but that's not really enough.
I also tried to import the interface directly as `import { EmailStrategy } from "my-packages/internal/path/email.strategy.ts"` but that's also semi decent